# Add series to chart

Tags: excel, series, excel-charts, vba

I use Holebase for work and it would be very useful for me if excel knew how to differentiate the start of a new series since the macro we have so far only displays one series by making a gap between series.
So the macro I'm trying to manipulate was taken from here and has already been adjusted since the previous one suited a purpose slightly different.

What I want is: Everytime I find a new BH on column A plot a distinct series with the values from column C and column D (x and y respectively) till the next BH on column A.

I managed to sort it out. So the macro first deletes all series inside the chart, second everytime time there is a new value / text on column A it displays the data shown on column C (X) and column D (Y).

No I have only one more problem to sort it out. The x range needs to have a minimum date since excel always adopts 1900 by default

```
Sub MakeCharts()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rAllData As Range
Dim rChartData As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim rwStart As Long, rwCnt As Long
Dim s As Series
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long

Set sh = ActiveSheet

sh.ChartObjects(1).Activate

'Set chrt = sh.ChartObjects(1)

For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
  s.Delete
Next s

With sh
    ' Get reference to all data
    Set rAllData = .Range(.[A1], .[A1].End(xlDown)).Resize(, 4)
    ' Get reference to first cell in data range
    rwStart = 2
    Set cl = rAllData.Cells(rwStart, 1)

    Do While cl <> ""

        'Capture the first cell in the source range then trap the color
        Set SourceRange = rAllData.Cells(rwStart, 5)
        SourceRangeColor = SourceRange.Interior.Color

        ' cl points to first cell in a station data set
        ' Count rows in current data set
        rwCnt = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
           CountIfs(rAllData.Columns(1), cl.Value)

        ' Get reference to current data set range
        Set rChartData = rAllData.Cells(rwStart, 1).Resize(rwCnt, 4)

        'ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add _
        'Source:=rChartData

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

        .XValues = rChartData.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 1)

        .Values = rChartData.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 1)

        .Name = rAllData.Cells(rwStart, 1)

        .MarkerBackgroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        .MarkerForegroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        '.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor (line colour for workbook 2007-2010)
        '.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor  (line colour for workbook 2007-2010)
        '.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor  (line colour for workbook 2007-2010)

        .Interior.Color = SourceRangeColor
        .Border.Color = SourceRangeColor

        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlTimeScale
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = Application.Min.Range("C:C")
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = Application.Max.Range("C:C")


                ' Get next data set
        rwStart = rwStart + rwCnt
        Set cl = rAllData.Cells(rwStart, 1)
    End With
    Loop


End With
```

End Sub

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2pwT.jpg)

Comment: I have deleted all my comments above so that your question doesn't get cluttered. You may delete all your comments as well

Comment: Hi Siddhart I sorted the code.. You can see it above. Now i only need to figure out how to make the x axis to have the minimum date instead of since 1900